# Class method as winAPI callback

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it feasible to set the winAPI message callback function as a method of a class. If so, how would this be best implemented? I wonder if it is even possible.

Sorry for the short question, hopefully you will be able to provide useful responses.

Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use non-`static` member functions for C callbacks.

However, usually C callbacks have a user data pointer that's routed to the callback. This can be explored to do what you want with the help of a `static` member functions:

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!

typedef void (*callback)(int blah, void* user_data);

void some_func(callback cb, void* user_data);

class my_class {
public:
  // ...
  void call_some_func()
  {
     some_func(&callback_,this);
  }
private:
  void callback(int blah)
  {
    std::cout << blah << '\n';
  }
  static void callback_(int blah, void* user_data)
  {
    my_class* that = static_cast<my_class*>(user_data);
    that->callback(blah);
  }
};
```

Comment: It's a little confusing but I understand the concept (I think).

Comment: I get it now. I don't think it would compile because callback_ was declared after it's use in call_some_func();

Comment: @Alexander: Inlined member functions are compiled as if they were defined immediately after their class' definition. So that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you use MSVC, and target x86-32 (not x86-64), you may use __stdcall convention for member function. (__cdecl works too)

With __stdcall **this** will be passed as first parameter, so you can write

```
typedef void(__stdcall *callback_t)(void* arg);
void set_callback(callback_t callback, void* callbackParameter);

struct Foo
{
   int x;
   void __stdcall someCallback() { this->x = 1; }
};
```

but

```
Foo foo;
set_callback((callback_t)&Foo::someCallback, this);
```

Will not work: you can't directly cast member function pointer to pointer by standard. You should use a workaround to make this working:

First, assert that &Foo::someCallback has the same size as void*

```
static_assert(sizeof(&Foo::someCallback) == sizeof(void*), "");
// or assert()
```

This assert may fail, if there may be multiple inheritance, and someCallback is virtual.
To disallow multiple inheritance, use __single_inheritance keyword:

```
struct __single_inheritance Foo { /* ....*/ };
```

Second, you should cast &Foo::someCallback to callback_t by using

```
union
{
    void(__stdcall Foo::*src)();
    callback_t dst;    
} u = {&Foo::someCallback};
set_callback(u.dst, this);
```

or

```
void(__stdcall Foo::*temp)() = &Foo::someCallback;
set_callback(*(callback_t*)&temp, this);
```

It works only if you can pass **this** to callback as first parameter.

If you can't, you can try to dynamically generate callback stubs in assembly :) Allocate an executable memory and write there

```
B9 XX XX XX XX mov ecx, <this>
68 XX XX XX XX push <function member address>
C3 ret
```

It will be callback stub, which will convert __stdcall to __thiscall.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that it has the right signature, and the right calling convention, you can pass static class methods as callback functions for various Win32 APIs. You can't use non-static methods, as they expect one more implicit parameter (the `this` pointer), which the Win32 APi can't give to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an appropriate static member function of a class as a callback function from Windows APIs.